# Using unicode char code in regular expression

Tags: python, regex, unicode

Simplifying my task, lets say I want to find any words written in Hebrew in some web page.
So I know that Hebrew char codes are `U+05D0` to `U+05EA`.
I want to write something like:

```
expr = "[\u05D0-\u05EA]+"
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Countries"    

web_handle = urllib2.urlopen(url)
website_text = website_handle.read()    
matches = sre.findall(exp, website_text)
for item in matches:
    print item
```

The output I would expect is:

> עברית

But instead the out  put is a lot of Chinese/Japanese chars.

Comment: @stribizhev It won't find anything. Maybe I should use HTML codes instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression should be:

```
expr = u"[\u05D0-\u05EA]+"
```

Notice the 'u' at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use standard representation of unicode in python within a character class :

```
re.findall([\u05D0-\u05EA], website_text,re.U)
```

Comment: It won't find anything. Maybe I should use HTML codes instead? `&#1488` to `&#1514`

Comment: @Sanich No it doesn't works in python, maybe you need to decode your text, actually its based on your text.

Comment: the text is HTML web page

Comment: @Sanich Can you add a sample data to your question? with your expected output?